# How to run function before WKWebView finishes loading?

Tags: swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I'm creating a Swift iOS project that has multiple WKWebViews that display external websites. Some of these websites I don't have administrative access to, so I use some code to hide a `div` class. This works fine, but the element is hidden AFTER the page loads, so for a few seconds the `div` element is shown to the user. See below:

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("finished")
    let elementID = "some_element"
    let removeElementIdScript = "var element = document.getElementById('\(elementID)'); element.parentElement.removeChild(element);"
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(removeElementIdScript) { (response, error) in
        debugPrint("removed")
    }
}
```

Is there a way to implement this code before the view loads? Or, if that's not possible, how can I place a mask or hide the view until it loads. I want to avoid showing the `div` element at all costs.

I've already tried putting the code into the `didStartProvisionalNavigation` function, but I assume because it runs before the view has loaded, the element isn't present in the view for it to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `WKUserScript`, configured as part of the `WKUserContentController` (defined in the `WKWebViewConfiguration`). That will probably be good enough, but you can push it further by implementing a content blocker. See `WKContentRuleStore` for setting those up internally to your app, and specifically [Safari Content-Blocking Rules Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/creating_a_content_blocker#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016265) for details on the syntax.

Comment: What if I wanted to remove multiple `div` elements at once?

Comment: I'm not certain why this would be different?